# Cloning from github to a heroku app

Tags: heroku, github

I'm working on a deployment app that runs on Heroku that allows me to push branches from a cloned git repo to other machines for deployment.

When I try to clone the repository from github (from a ruby app, if it matters), I get the following error:

`Host key verification failed`

`fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.`

To address this issue, I checked in an RSA key which I have added to my github account to the heroku app, but the problem persists.

I have attempted to call `ssh-add` from my app but get the following error:

`Could not open a connection to your authentication agent`

I've tried opening a bash shell with the ssh-agent, with no effect. Here is the block of code where I attempt to add the ssh key.

`ruby
def self.add_ssh_key(path='~/.ssh')
  activate_ssh_agent = %x{exec ssh-agent bash}
  command = %x{ssh-add #{path}}
  if $?.exitstatus != 0
    msg = "Error: unable to add ssh-key"
  end
end`

Is there some approach I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I've altered my approach a bit.

Using SSH has proven to be frustrating so I just switched to checking out via https instead, the credentials can be put into the actual repo name, and these credentials can be included as  environment variables on the heroku app.

Relevant code:

```
def self.clone_repo(repository_address)
  username = ENV["GITHUB_USER_NAME"]
  password = ENV["GITHUB_PASSWORD"]
  repo = "https://#{username}:#{password}@github.com/#{repository_address}"
  command = %x{git clone #{repo}}

  if $?.exitstatus != 0
    msg = "Git error: unable to clone repository #{repository_address}"
  end
end
```